# Return array in Dojo

Tags: dojo

I'm new to Dojo and having a hard time with the following piece of code. I don't understand why the chartData is empty at the very end. I created this method based on an example on the Dojo site.

The code is the following:

```
        function(xhr, json, arrayUtil, number, Chart, theme) {

            var chartData = [];

            var def = xhr.get({
                url: "cpuusage.json",
                handleAs: "json"
            });

            def.then(function(res){
                var data = [];

                    arrayUtil.forEach(res.chart, function(chart){
                        data[chart.x] = number.parse(chart.y);
                    });
                chartData = data;
                console.info("chartData1: ", chartData);
            }, function(err){
                console.error("Failed to load JSON data");
            });
```

The first console.info within def.then says that the chartData has the correct value. When I however print the value of chartData after the def.then method finished, it's empty.

How can I make sure that chartData has the **same value in and after the def.then call**. Many thanks

Comment: I've updated my question based on previous answer.

Comment: I think I got it now. Instead of trying to use chartData outside of xhr and then I need to initiate my chart from within the 'then' call so the chartData will be available. So the above code is actually correct but chartData can only be used within the 'then' call. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

the, methods in the xhr are all async by nature, but they return a promise. if you want to execute some code after the xhr method it should look like this:

```
    function(xhr, json, arrayUtil, number, Chart, theme) {

        var chartData = [];

        xhr.get({
            url: "cpuusage.json",
            handleAs: "json",
            load: function(jsonData) {
                arrayUtil.forEach(jsonData.chart, function(chart){
                    chartData[chart.x] = number.parse(chart.y);
                });
                console.info("JSON loaded from server:  ", chartData);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.error("Failed to load JSON data");
            }
        }).then(function(jsonData){
             console.info("chartData: ", chartData);
        });
```

by using the then function of the promise, you make sure your code executes after the AJAX call

Comment: Thanks but this still doesn't set chartData after xhr exit. Is it possible at all or do you have to 'save' the data in a node on the html?

Comment: your problem is that you are dealing with ajax, that means asyncronius, and asyncronious methods exit before being finalized.if you need chartData, you need to chain to another function that executes after the xhr finalizes, that means either using the "then" function or calling the function inside the load method.

Comment: NOTE: seting to a html node, will mean the same problem you already have, it won't be set by the time xhr exits

Comment: just remembered, check the dojo documentation, there is a way to make it a syncronious call. but this means your page will freeze while performing xhr

Comment: thanks, I hope we can work this out. I definitely need asynchronous solution. I tried your example but it doesn't work unfortunately. According to the Dojo documentation the load and then functions are almost the same so having them both won't necessarily help. At the moment the only solution I can see is creating a global array with setters and insert json data there with the setter. What do you think?

Comment: Again, my goal is to set the chartData array that is declared at the beginning and have that data available after the callback.